# Can I run python script in Alteryx that uses pandas and connects to MS SQL server using pyodbc

Tags: python, pandas, alteryx

I'm a trainee at an organization that uses Microsoft Excel SQL server as database environment and alteryx as application to extract, transform and load (ETL) data. At my university we use MySQL Workbench as database environment and Pentaho Data Integration as application for ETL.

I have a python script that I run in Spyder and it uses the libraries mysql.connector and pandas. Today I came to the conclusion that the organization will not be able to use any of the software I use for school (MySQL workbench, spyder and Pentaho data integration). So I want to transfer and transform my project to the software that the organization IS able to use.

I'm not familiar with Alteryx and haven't used it yet. I found out that alteryx is able to run a python script but for me it's unclear if it has restriction. So my question is: Does anybody know if alteryx can execute a Python script that uses/does the following things?:

1. `import pyodbc`, to connect with the SQL server database
2. `import pandas` to be able to execute the rest of the script and write a dataframe to Excel

Any answers are welcome and i'll be thankful

Comment: Alterxy has its own dB connections that will most likely be set up for you. Don't sweat this stuff, during your on boarding you'll be shown how to work with your in-house stack.

Comment: Short answer is yes, you can do that. If you have difficulty it would be with your company's security, not the Alteryx application. Seems pointless though, as Alteryx can talk directly to SQL Server, and output directly in Excel format. If you want to use Python, save money and just use Python directly, rather than wrapping it in Alteryx.